# Are unique product description on product variations required for SEO?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, products

My website has several products which have some product variations, for example color, and each variation has its own page, such as:

- Fender Stratocaster Red
- Fender Stratocaster Blue

Am I supposed to write an unique content description for every single product page? Am I penalized if I include the same description in all of them? What is your recommendation here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Duplicate Content**

When it comes to duplicate content, Google does not penalise the website or page, but actually discounts one in favour of whatever one it believes is the original version. So basically your content won't be considered for your pages search ranking.

- **Option 1:**
  As the core product is the same, I would recommend adding a drop-down
  for colour. This allows you to keep all of your content and gives your customers the option of colour.  If you want to rank for colour
  choices of your product, I would add something like, *available in
  red, blue, and rainbow unicorn.*
- **Option 2:**
  Add unique content for each product. Time-consuming, but if your
  users can't pick the colour, this might be the best approach.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Option 1 is not possible because people use to search and browse instruments by finish or color.  In our niche, these variations are considered by customers like single products. I checked what is doing one of the biggest instrument shops and they are duplicating content: [Example1][1] [Example2][2]

   [1]: https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/GremlinCTurq--tone-king-gremlin-5-watt-1x12-inch-tube-combo-with-attenuator-turquoise

  [2]: (https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/GremlinCTurq--tone-king-gremlin-5-watt-1x12-inch-tube-combo-with-attenuator-)turquoise]